# "Multisite support is not enabled." After Multisite Config Changes

Tags: multisite

I'm having a problem getting the "My Sites" option on the toolbar.  I've followed the steps on the book WordPress Multisite Administration and every site tutorial which are all the same.  And it never shows up.  This is on my dev machine running on Docker and I have restarted from scratch several times.

I'm using [www.dmohave.gov](http://www.dmohave.gov) which is just an entry in my hosts' file:

```
127.0.0.1 www.dmohave.gov
```

I first edit wp-config.php with the database settings and for Multisite

```
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
```

I then run through the install and setup my network which gives me the following update to wp-config.php

```
# define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'www.dmohave.gov');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

and .htaccess in the same root path as wp-config.php

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between `BEGIN WordPress` and `END WordPress` are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
# <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

    # add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
    RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
    RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
    RewriteRule . index.php [L]
# </IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I also tried

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between `BEGIN WordPress` and `END WordPress` are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

    # add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
    RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
    RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
    RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

In my Apache conf file I use the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName dmohave.gov
ServerAlias dmohave.gov *.dmohave.gov

    Redirect permanent / https://www.dmohave.gov/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    # The primary domain for this host
    ServerName dmohave.gov
    # Optionally have other subdomains also managed by this Virtual Host
    ServerAlias dmohave.gov *.dmohave.gov

    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
    DocumentRoot /var/web/www/build/

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/dmohave.gov-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/dmohave.gov-access.log combined

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/selfsigned.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/selfsigned.key


    <Directory /var/web/www/build/>
        # Require all granted
        # Allow local .htaccess to override Apache configuration settings
        # AllowOverride all

        Options +FollowSymlinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted

        # Options FollowSymLinks
        # AllowOverride All
        # Require all granted       
    </Directory>

    # Enable RewriteEngine
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteOptions inherit

    # Block .svn, .git
    RewriteRule \.(svn|git)(/)?$ - [F]

    # Catchall redirect to www.example1.com
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^www.dmohave\.gov [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^$
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)         https://www.dmohave.gov/$1 [L,R]

    # Recommended: XSS protection
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
        Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
    </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

With the permissions:

[image: Working]

Everything loads properly but I just don't get access to "Network Admin" on the top of the toolbar

[image]

like this sample

[image]

If I go to the following URL: https://www.dmohave.gov/wp-admin/network/ I get an error

```
"Multisite support is not enabled."
```

**Solution**

OK I figured it out.  I added the defines after the following block of code:

```
/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    define( 'ABSPATH', __DIR__ . '/' );
}

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php';
```

Once I moved it before that block everything worked

Comment: Are you sure you have `define('MULTISITE', true);` ? That ought to be enough to pass that check - it's the first thing that [is_multisite()](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/5.4.2/wp-includes/load.php#L1087) tests.

Comment: It is.  I even re-typed it and restarted the Docker container and it's still not working.  It should be so easy from reading the instructions.